# Chrome jquery ajax to external api error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using jquery to hit an external api using ajax.

```
$.ajax({

                url: https://blahblah,
                method: "GET",                    
                contentType: "text/plain", 
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                accept: "application/json",
                async: true,
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, Accept",
                success: function (data) { //more code}
```

Everything works great in IE but because of Chrome's Same origin policy its not working. This is the error I am getting in the console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://blahblah. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:8889' is therefore not allowed access.

localhost/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

This is what the headers look like

```
Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 15:05:44 GMT
Server: xxxxx
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,x-frame-options
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:blahblah
Origin:http://localhost:8889
```

Referer:http://localhost:8889/

Because this is a .net MVC4 IIS 7.5 app I tried setting the custom headers in WEB.CONFIG file but it didn't work either

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>

    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*"/>

  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to inform you that it is impossible to do javascript ajax without first installing a cors plugin that will allow you to do so

Example of such a plugin: [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Comment: That's ridiculous. There has to be a workaround. You can't tell all your users to install a chrome plugin to use your app